# Panel not visible in Java Frame

Tags: java, panel, frame

I am trying to create a Calculator application using Java. For Now I am creating the window with all buttons and Panel to display the numbers clicked.
Somehow the panel I added to the Frame is not displayed. Could anyone help me. What is the mistake I am doing?

```
package com.wells.eda;
import java.awt.*;
public class Calc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator c = new Calculator();

    try{
        Frame fm= c.NewFrame("Calculator",330,310);
        c.NewButton(fm, "1",10,110);
        c.NewButton(fm, "2",90,110);
        c.NewButton(fm, "3",170,110);
        c.NewButton(fm, "4",10,160);
        c.NewButton(fm, "5",90,160);
        c.NewButton(fm, "6",170,160);
        c.NewButton(fm, "7",10,210);
        c.NewButton(fm, "8",90,210);
        c.NewButton(fm, "9",170,210);
        c.NewButton(fm, "00",10,260);
        c.NewButton(fm, "0",90,260);
        c.NewButton(fm, "Reserved",170,260);
        c.NewButton(fm, "+",250,110);
        c.NewButton(fm, "-",250,160);
        c.NewButton(fm, "*",250,210);
        c.NewButton(fm, "/",250,260);
        c.NewPanel(fm);
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        //fm.dispose();

        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("Exception happened");
        }
    }

}
class Calculator{

    public Frame NewFrame(String name,int length, int width) 
    {
        Frame fm = new Frame(name);
        fm.setLayout(null);
        fm.setResizable(false);
        fm.setSize(length,width);
        fm.setVisible(true);
        return(fm);
    }
    public void NewButton(Frame fm,String number,int xcordinate,int ycordinate) throws Exception
    {
        Button b = new Button (number);
        b.setBounds(xcordinate,ycordinate,70,40);
        //b.setVisible(true);
        fm.add(b);          
    }
    public void NewPanel(Frame fm)
    {
        Panel p= new Panel(null);
        fm.add(p);
        //p.setSize(100, 100);
        p.setBounds(10,10,250,100);
        p.setName("Panel");
        p.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your panel is not displayed because it is empty and you didn't set a specific layout that could make it visible.

e.g : fm.setLayout(null); ==> fm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

```
public void NewPanel(Frame fm)
{
    Panel p= new Panel(null);
    fm.add(p);
    //p.setSize(100, 100);
    p.setBounds(10,10,250,100);
    p.setName("Panel");
    p.setVisible(true);
}
```

try this :

```
public void NewPanel(Frame fm)
{
    Panel p= new Panel(null);
    fm.add(p);
    //p.setSize(100, 100);
    p.setBounds(10,10,250,100);
    p.setName("Panel");
    p.add(new JLabel("Test"));
    p.setVisible(true);
}
```

You will see your Panel arround the JLabel created

Comment: can't I add this to existing Frame without Layout? I am not aware of Layouts yet.

Comment: Layouts are used to tell how the components are going to be placed. You should use it every time, this is not very hard if you give a look to the GridLayout or the FlowLayout, for instance.

Comment: My bad. I just understood you set a null layout in order to place the components with their coordinates. Then the only problem is : your panel is empty. You are adding the buttons to the frame, not to the Panel